# Set 5 second delay before executing javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, transition

I'm trying to add a 5 second delay before executing a javascript function. The function is tied to a button click event. Ideally the user would click the link then there would be a 5 second delay before executing the function. Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
<input onclick="myFunction()" id="link" type="Submit" value="GO" style="border-radius: 5px;"/>

function myFunction() {
  style.transitionDelay = "5s"; 
  var url = window.location.href;
  var res = url.split("#");
  var hash = "#" + res[1];
  window.location = 'test123.com/go' + hash;
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);` what you want?

Comment: I forgot to mention the function is tied to a click event: <input onclick="myFunction()" id="link" type="Submit" value="GO" style="border-radius: 5px;"/>  -so basically once someone clicks I want there to be a 3-5 second delay before executing the function

Comment: edit your question and include a [mcve] - please

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use JS's `setTimeout` (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

For example:

```js
// define the function to call
function myFunction() {
  console.log('timed out');
  alert('ding!');
};

// get a handle on the button DOM element 
var btnElement = document.getElementById('btn');

// register event on button click
btnElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  // execute it in 5 secs (delay time is in milliseconds, so 5*1000=5000ms -> 5secs)
  setTimeout(myFunction, 5 * 1000);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the function is tied to a click event: <input onclick="myFunction()" id="link" type="Submit" value="GO" style="border-radius: 5px;"/>  -so basically once someone clicks I want there to be a 3-5 second delay before executing the function

Comment: I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has function `setInterval(callback, time);` so as in the example below you can just pass to the `onclick` event `setTimeout()` function with callback with name of your function and time in milliseconds.

Example:

```
<input onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 5000)" id="link" type="Submit" value="GO" style="border-radius: 5px;"/>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        alert(1);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: For newer programmers, it helps them understand what the code does (as well as seeing working code) - I suggest you add some comments on your answer to the benefit of the OP and others that bump into your answer later on.

Comment: looks like this one works as well. Can I add another check mark or only 1?

Comment: @Chris only one answer per question - if more than one works, select the best one for you and upvote the other ones :)

Comment: @Chris Do you mean something like this? `<input onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 1000); setTimeout(myFunction2, 5000)" id="link" type="Submit" value="GO" style="border-radius: 5px;"/>`

Comment: @Chris No problem. :)